# Could not cast value of type 'FlutterViewController' to 'UINavigationController'

Tags: ios, flutter, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to run an implementation of [mercado_pago_mobile_checkout](https://pub.dev/packages/mercado_pago_mobile_checkout/) in my Flutter project. When I run in Android Emulator, the function StartCheckout works correctly, but in iOS version, when the function StartCheckout is called, this error occurs:

```
2021-07-22 11:39:14.504430-0300 Runner[31296:218261] Could not cast value of type 'FlutterViewController' (0x10b5bab60) to 'UINavigationController' (0x128b638f0).
```

The code that is seems to be broken is the AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    
    var navigationController: UINavigationController?;
    
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    
    let flutterViewController: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    
    self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: flutterViewController);
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false);

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds);
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    self.window.makeKeyAndVisible();
    
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

The code of the function StartCheckout is:

```
   PaymentResult result = await MercadoPagoMobileCheckout.startCheckout(
      publicKey,
      _idCompra,
      // ignore: missing_return
    ).then((result) async {
      if (result.status != null) {
        bd
            .collection("bagagens")
            .document(_bagagem.id)
            .setData(_bagagem.toMap())
            .then((_) {
          bd
              .collection("minhas_bagagens")
              .document(_bagagem.idUsuario)
              .collection("bagagens")
              .document(_bagagem.id)
              .setData(_bagagem.toMap())
              .then((_) {
            // cria a bagagem comprada

            bd
                .collection("minhas_bagagens_compradas")
                .document(idUsuarioLogado)
                .collection("bagagens_compradas")
                .document(_bagagemComprada.id)
                .setData(_bagagemComprada.toMap())
                .then((_) {
              //salvar bagagem pública
              bd
                  .collection("bagagens_compradas")
                  .document(_bagagemComprada.id)
                  .setData(_bagagemComprada.toMap())
                  .then((_) async {

                    if (_compraComSaldo) {
                      Map<String, dynamic> dadosAtualizados = {"saldo": "0.00"};

                      bd
                          .collection("usuarios")
                          .document(_idUsuarioLogado)
                          .updateData(dadosAtualizados);
                    }

                Navigator.pop(_dialogContext);
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BarraPrincipal(0)));

                /// Notificação para o usuário vendedor

                await notificarUsuario([
                  _idOneSignal
                ], "Um usuário solicitou a compra de sua bagagem no voo ${_bagagem.identificadorVoo}.",
                    "Bagagem Solicitada");

                /// End Notificação
              });
            });
          });
        });
      } else {
        Navigator.pop(_dialogContext);
      }
    });
```

Somebody knows how to solve this error? Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Hello Mate have you got solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
let flutterViewController: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
```

to

```
let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(project: nil, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
```